# How do I get a php table to print a range of input values but, ignore the ones that are not filled in?

Tags: php, html

I have made a form for a company website that the user will populate with personal info. I want to use php to handle these values and then render them as a table that can be printed. I have done this before but only for forms where everything is filled in. I want to make this one to where if the user decides to leave a field blank then you will not see it in the php rendered page. I will post a small example below for reference to help with my issue, as of now I have no idea where to start.

Example form...

```
<form action="post">
    <p><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="job" name="job"></p>
</form>
```

In this example form I am gathering name, phone number, and occupation. At the bottom I would have a button to submit the info. A php doc will then handle the values and render them in a table set up like this...(assume I $_POST the variables above this table.)

```
'<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:' .$name. '</td>
        <td>Phone:' .$phone. '</td>
        <td>Job:' .$job. '</td>
    </tr>
</table>'
```

This works fine however if the customer decides NOT to give there phone number it looks like this...

Name: Alex

Phone:

Job: Fireman

What I need to do is make it to where if they DO fill out the phone number it will show it however if they do not I need it to look like this...

Name: Alex

Job: Fireman

My actual form is very long however I thought this example would be enough for someone to help me get started, thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: This is simple. Just use an if statement to check to see if the variable has a value. If it doesn't, don't display that portion of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the $_POST array and print out a key-value when it has value.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value != '')
    {
        echo ucwords($key) . ': ' . $value;
    }
}
```

**OR**

With table formatting

```
// Just set the table up as necessary
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value != '')
    {
        echo '<td>' . ucwords($key) . ': </td><td>' . $value . '</td>;
    }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Interesting and especially dynamic approach.

Comment: However, it doesn't handle outputting in an HTML table format, although that could be added to the code.

Comment: This one may be above my pay grade but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't format it as table, but that is easy enough to implement, simply by formatting the string around.

Comment: Err...this particular setup won't work. Please put the `<tr>` tags around the foreach. I took the liberty to edit that in.

Comment: @ABBryan this would basically loop over each element in the $_POST array and echo each element key and value in it's own row in a table, try it and see

Comment: In this example where do I put the Catagories such as "Name:" and "Phone Number:"

Comment: @ABBryan You put them in, by naming your POST fiels accordingly. It takes the keys...the names of the fields in your form...and prints them before the colon.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium The formatting is subjective, but I understand what you mean at least in terms of replicating what OP has.  I've edited it to reflect that format. (For some reason, your edit doesn't show)

Comment: So the $key is built into php or am i declaring it when i put $key=>$value

Comment: @ABBryan The $key variable is defined in the foreach() statement.  But because of the syntax, $key corresponds to the "name" value from your HTML form and $value corresponds to the input value from your HTML form.  For example, the first loop through the foreach will grab the following: $key=>$value will be name=>[name_input]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, based on your string.

```
$table = '<table>
<tr>';
if (!empty($name)) {
    $table .= '<td>Name:' .$name. '</td>';
}
if (!empty($phone)) {
    $table .= '<td>Phone:' .$phone. '</td>';
}
if (!empty($job)) {
    $table .= '<td>Job:' .$job. '</td>';
}
$table .= '</tr>
</table>';

echo $table;
```

Comment: I MUST learn to type faster...and would the person who downvoted this answer please explain why they did it?

Comment: Thank you for your response I am new to working with php so I have had some trouble initially, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking however why do you use the $table is this required. I have set up many pages using php that I simply defined the table like HTML then populated it with php variables.

Comment: `$table` is just a variable to hold the string as it is constructed then you can echo it out with `echo $table`

Comment: Why not format your strings like this: `"<td>Name: $name</td>"`? I don't think this would introduce any problems?

Comment: @MMM That's a viable alternative, I just copied from the OP's question and he was using concatenation rather than interpolation, so I stayed with it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using the `empty` function of PHP.
Try this in your processing PHP file:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
if(!empty($name)) echo "<td>Name: $name</td>";
if(!empty($phone)) echo "<td>Phone: $phone</td>";
if(!empty($job)) echo "<td>Job: $job</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Upvoted again as I can't see why this deserves a downvote when it is essentially the same as mine

Comment: @fullybaked It really is. I wonder who downvoted our answers...and why.